# Thins Lens Equation Question

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses

According to my textbook, it says that according to the thin lens equation, object distance and image distance vary inversely. However, when I do a converging lens simulation, as I increase the distance the object is from the lens, the distance the image is from the lens also increases. Why is this? Is there a sign convention I am not aware of?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is an easy calculation:

$$ -\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a'}=\frac{1}{f'} $$

$$ \frac{1}{a'}=\frac{1}{f'}+\frac{1}{a} $$

$$ \frac{1}{a'}=\frac{a}{af'}+\frac{f'}{af'} $$

$$ \frac{1}{a'}=\frac{a+f'}{af'}$$

$$ a'=\frac{af'}{a+f'}$$

So it is not inversely proportional, as it is not $\propto \frac{1}{a}$ only.

Comment: why is 1/a negative?

Comment: Isn't it the lens equation?

Comment: I thought there's no negative in the lens equation

Comment: @54284User It all depends on which one of the many sign conventions is being used.